# Django StreamingHttpResponse not setting correct filename

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Struggling with this one... I am trying to use `StreamingHttpResponse` to output a csv of data. The file itself is constructed fine, but for some reason the filename is being set incorrectly across different browsers. I'm using Django Rest Framework with a custom csv renderer. The `CSVRenderer` takes the standard data from a Django Rest Framework `ReadOnlyModelViewset`and renders it using `StreamingHttpResponse`. The `CSVRenderer` was written based on [Django docs explaining how to output a csv](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/outputting-csv/)

```
import csv

from rest_framework.renderers import BaseRenderer
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse

class Echo(object):
    '''An object that implements just the write method of the file-like
    interface.
    '''

    def write(self, value):
        '''Write the value by returning it, instead of storing in a buffer.
        '''

        return value


class CSVRenderer(BaseRenderer):
    '''Renderer class to generate basic csvs of the data supplied by the
    serializer
    '''

    media_type = 'text/csv'
    format = 'csv'

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):

        rows = []

        first_data_row = next(iter(data['results']), None)

        # Create header rows if data present
        if first_data_row:
            rows.append(list(first_data_row.keys()))

            # print the data to rows
            for row in data['results']:
                rows.append(list(row.values()))

        pseudo_buffer = Echo()
        writer = csv.writer(pseudo_buffer)

        response = StreamingHttpResponse((writer.writerow(row) for row in rows), content_type='text/csv')

        response['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv; name="export.csv"'
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="export.csv"'

        return response
```

So when I do a GET request to a url e.g. `http://example.com/api/mydata?format=csv` in IE I get a file containing the correct data named `mydata.txt` which is the wrong filename and extension! In Firefox I get a file containing the correct data named `XuKsgJ.csv` which is the right extension but just a random filename!

I guess I'm not setting something somewhere, but I can't figure out where. Any suggestions? Running Django 1.10.8, Django Rest Framework 3.5.3. I also tried using [djangorestframework-csv](https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-rest-framework-csv) in place of my custom `CSVRenderer` but got the same output. Anything to do with my middleware? This is what I have in my `settings.py`

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've also met this problem, but I see in your code that you were wrong overriding ***render*** method. Class CSVRenderer's have render function which return string, not response.

```
def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None): ...
"""
   Renders serialized *data* into CSV. For a dictionary:
"""
```

cause this function should return string, not response object.

Actually there is one way to change the file name:

just adding ***finaliez_response*** method (it's last method before returning response) into your API View

```
  def finalize_response(self, request, response, *args, **kwargs):
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="export.csv"'
    return super().finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
```

Hope that it will help who meet  this problem!

Comment: Yes this worked, I ended up putting a check in to ensure this `content-disposition` was only set for csvs `if request.accepted_media_type == 'text/csv'`

Comment: Thanks though it was still on my bug list!

Comment: try to use this library https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-rest-framework-csv Instead of hard coding.  I think it can cover your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can override render method and set filename there

```
 def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context={}, writer_opts=None):
        rendered_data = super(MyRenderer, self).render(data, media_type, renderer_context, writer_opts)
        renderer_context['response']['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % ('ab.csv')
        return rendered_data
```